# PostCSS error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin

Tags: gulp, postcss

The error is coming from the `postcss` plugin, I think I may have written it incorrectly.

I'm trying to add `cssnano` and `autoprefixer` to the `postcss` plugin.

```
gulp/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:143
        throw new Error(i + ' is not a PostCSS plugin');
        ^

Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin
    at Processor.normalize (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sites/gulp/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:143:15)
    at new Processor (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sites/gulp/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:51:25)
    at postcss (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sites/gulp/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:73:10)
    at Transform.stream._transform (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sites/gulp/node_modules/gulp-postcss/index.js:47:5)
    at Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:300:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:286:5)
    at Transform.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:214:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.ondata (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sites/gulp/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:531:20)
Mac-a45e60e72dad:gulp JoeKonst$
```

My code:

```
// Dependancies
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    compass = require('gulp-compass'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    nano = require('cssnano'),
    del = require('del'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function(){
    gulp.src('sass/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}), nano()]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));

    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

// Tasks
gulp.task('default', ['styles']);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are using the [`gulp-autoprefixer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) package. That's simply a wrapper around the original [`autoprefixer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) package that turns it into a gulp plugin, so you can do `.pipe(autoprefixer())`.

However `postcss` expects the original package itself, not the gulp plugin.

So instead of this:

```
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
```

You need to install the `autoprefixer` package and do this:

```
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
```

Comment: Had the same issue also with gulp-cssnano - it also cannot be used as PostCSS plugin. Had to require and use the "cssnano" instead "gulp-cssnano". Visually it looks almost the same and as a Gulp newbie i must say it is ez to overlook.

Comment: extra benefit: now you can „suddenly“ use parameters inside your autoprefixer: `    .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer({browsers: ['iOS ...']}) ]))`

Answer (score 46):

@rizkit - I found the [fix](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1358#issuecomment-693175534) and it's simple. Just run `npm i -d postcss` and the problem is solved.

Basically, you need both `gulp-postcss` and `postcss` plugins in your dependencies for this to work correctly. I'm assuming the `gulp-postcss` plugin will need to update the `postcss` package reference in the project to fix it properly, so we only need to include `gulp-postcss` in the future.

Comment: `npm i -d postcss` worked for me! I upgraded to Ng12 and encountered this issue.

Answer (score 17):

#### Tailwindcss & React issue

For anyone facing the above issue while setting up a react project with tailwindcss, running `npm i postcss -D` worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `autoprefixer 10` you might stumble upon that problem again, there is a github issue related to that with some links and explanations: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1358

tl;dr:

- for `postcss-cli` and `gulp-postcss` you have to wait for an update, for `PostStylus` you might never get an update.
- or add `postcss` as a devDependency

Comment: Downgrading to Autoprefixer v9 using `npm i -D autoprefixer@9` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was still getting this error along with *cannot find build-manifest.json*
when I upgraded to Next js v 10 and upgraded tailwind, autoprefixer and postcss.

I had to **upgrade yarn** as well to finally get rid of the errors.

The updated dev dependencies in my package.json were as:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below minimum devDependencies in your package.json

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "gulp": "4",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-mode": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-stylelint": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "stylelint": "^13.3.3",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.17.2"
```