# object Object is not a PostCSS plugin - error while building nrwl library project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, nrwl-nx, ng-build

We have an [nrwl-nx](/questions/tagged/nrwl-nx) workspace library project (on Angular 8), under which we have 3-4 [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) libraries. Its ng serve works fine, `ng build my-lib` used to work as well.

However, on our build agent, recently we started getting below error.

> C:\pathToProject> my-workspace build:my-lib C:\pathToProject
> C:\pathToProject> ng build --project my-lib
>
> Building Angular Package
> Building entry point '@my-scope/my-lib'
> Rendering Stylesheets
>
> BUILD ERROR
> [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin
> Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin
> at Processor.normalize (C:\pathToProject\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:145:15)
> at new Processor (C:\pathToProject\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:51:25)
> at postcss (C:\pathToProject\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:73:10)
> at createPostCssProcessor (C:\pathToProject\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ng-v5\entry-point\resources\stylesheet.transform.js:73:12)
> at Object. (C:\pathToProject\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ng-v5\entry-point\resources\stylesheet.transform.js:36:30)
> at Generator.next ()
> at C:\pathToProject\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ng-v5\entry-point\resources\stylesheet.transform.js:7:71
> at new Promise ()
> at __awaiter (C:\pathToProject\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ng-v5\entry-point\resources\stylesheet.transform.js:3:12)

The same command worked fine on other machines until we cleared cache, reinstalled the same nodejs version and did ng build lib-project to troubleshoot. [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) v10.16.0, [npm](/questions/tagged/npm) v6.9.0.

I tried with `nodejs v12.20.0`, but it seems like as issue comes with this version as well.

Checked other questions on SO as well
[PostCSS error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090111/postcss-error-object-object-is-not-a-postcss-plugin), however, we are not using `autoprefixer`.

Has anyone encountered the issue? Any help would be appreciated. __/\__

Answer (score 4):

using `npm install -D postcss` worked for me.

Same [issue here](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1358).